# How to build Angular 5 to Django static folder with hashing enabled

Tags: python, django, angular

I have a Django app that has an Angular 5 frontend connected by Django REST.

Currently deployment only works with hashing disabled (--output-hashing none), because in uls.py I can only access a copy of index.html ("ang_home.html") in the template folder.

```
ng build --prod --output-path .../backend/src/static/ --watch --output-hashing none --aot=false --env=prod
```

I would now like to change my urls.py so that the newly created index.html in the django static folder is accessed directly so that I can use hashing.

```
url(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="ang_home.html"), name='home'),
```

The current solution is annoying because I would have to copy the index.html code into ang_home.html manually with every change.

Shortly: I want

```
url(r'^.*', index.html in the static folder), name='home'),
```

Comment: Is there a question or what part are you wondering about? a `r'^'` at the bottom of your url_patterns will catch all unmatched URLs if thats the part.

Comment: It is not. I want to change TemplateView.as_view(template_name="ang_home.html") to index.html in the static files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a not perfect solution in the form of a simple sh script using fswatch. Maybe someone has the same problem and it helps.

```
printf "Index Updater\n"
fswatch -o ./backend/src/static/index.html | while read num ; \
  do \
    DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
    printf "Copy updated index.html => ang_home.html @${DATE} \n"
    cp ./backend/src/static/index.html ./backend/src/templates/ang_home.html
  done
```